# Plotting derivative of NDSolve solution

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to plot the derivative of an `NDSolve` solution. My code is :

```
K = 0.01; u1 = 0; u2 = 1; u3 = 3; xmin = -750; xmax = 750; steep = \
50; tmin = 0; tmax = 500; Diff = 10.;

sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], 
     t] == -K*(u[t, x] - u1)*(u[t, x] - u2)*(u[t, x] - u3) + 
     Diff*D[u[t, x], x, x],
   u[t, xmin] == u1, u[t, xmax] == u3, 
   u[0, x] == (u3 + u1*Exp[-x/steep])/(1 + Exp[-x/steep])}, 
  u, {x, xmin, xmax}, {t, tmin, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 1000, "MinPoints" -> 1000}}]

Animate[Plot[D[u[t, x], x] /. sol, {x, xmin/2, xmax/2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{xmin/2, xmax/2}, {u1 - 0.5, u3 + 0.5}}], {t, tmin, 
  tmax}]
```

and I get the errors:

```
General::ivar: -374.969 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -374.969 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -343.719 is not a valid variable. >>

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

General::ivar: -374.969 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -343.719 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -312.469 is not a valid variable. >>

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

General::ivar: -374.969 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -374.969 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -343.719 is not a valid variable. >>

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

General::ivar: -374.985 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -374.985 is not a valid variable. >>

General::ivar: -359.679 is not a valid variable. >>

General::stop: Further output of General::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

I have tried to look at some other answers to this question, all suggesting using the method I have tried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to use `Evaluate`. Also, not good idea to use `UpperCase`, `K` for example is Mathematica symbol. And Manipulate is better to use than Animate. And better to define the pde, ic, bc, separately than put them all inside the call to `NDSolve` so it is more clear.

[image]

```
k = 0.01;
u1 = 0;
u2 = 1;
u3 = 3;
xmin = -750;
xmax = 750;
steep = 50;
tmin = 0;
tmax = 500;
diff = 10.;

pde = D[u[t, x], t] == -k*(u[t, x] - u1)*(u[t, x] - u2)*(u[t, x] - u3) 
       + diff*D[u[t, x], x, x];

bc = {u[t, xmin] == u1, u[t, xmax] == u3};
ic = u[0, x] == (u3 + u1*Exp[-x/steep])/(1 + Exp[-x/steep]);

sol = NDSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u,{x, xmin, xmax},{t, tmin, tmax},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 1000, "MinPoints" -> 1000}}]

Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[D[u[t, x], x] /. sol], {x, xmin/2, xmax/2},
  PlotRange -> {{xmin/2, xmax/2}, {0, .05}}],

 {{t, tmin, "time"}, tmin, tmax, .1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {t}
 ]
```